# Find pmf for the number of coin tosses until two successive heads appear

Tags: probability

Suppose a fair coin is flipped until $H$ appears in two successive flips. Let $X$ denote the total number of flips for this to happen. Find the probability mass function of $X$.

Comment: Show us your work this isn't  a do my  homework site

Answer (score 2):

The probability the event happens after exactly $0$ flip or $1$ flip is of course ${\bf 0}$.

The probability it happens after exactly $2$ flips you get $HH$ is of course ${\bf 1/4}$ ($1/2 \times 1/2)$.

The probability it first happens after exactly $3$ flips is the probability of $THH$, or ${\bf 1/8}$.

The probability it first happens after exactly $4$ flips is the probability of $HTHH$ or $TTHH$, or ${\bf 1/4}$.

The probability it first happens after exactly $5$ flips is the probability of $TTTHH$, $HTTHH$, or $THTHH$, or ${\bf 3/16}$.

The probability it first happens after exactly $6$ flips is the probability of $TTTTHH$, $THTTHH$, $HTTTHH$, $HTHTHH$, or $TTHTHH$, or ${\bf 5/32}$.

I'll let you continue...  The key idea is that there can be no $HH$ before the final three "slots," that the final three slots must be $THH$, and that you sum over the probability of each such "successful" sequence.